# Allow / show post comments in category pages

Tags: posts, categories, comments

Is there any way to allow the users of a website to write comments (and also see the already published comments) on one post when it's displayed in a category page?

I'm not looking to let the category itself to be commented. I want the specific post to be commented without having to leave the category page.

Thanks

Comment: Sure, you should be able to get comments for each post within the archive loop. You'll likely need to create a child theme and then make the modification in a file like `category.php` or `archive.php`. What have you tried so far?

Comment: There's no `category.php`  in my project. Given my less than basic knowledge of php, I've only tried to insert the conditional `if ( comments_open()...` from the `single.php` file inside the conditional `while ( have_posts() )...` in the `archive.php`. Nothing happened